# Matlab surf plot remove offset (nonzero)

Tags: matlab, 3d, offset

I have some data which I am plotting using the surf command.
Its pretty simple,

`data=xlsread('./sample_55_data.xlsx');
 surf(data,'EdgeColor','none');`

However, it produces a plot which is offset in some dimensions from zero.
I can't figure out how to remove this.

Comment: you can post a link to an external website and someone can upload the picture for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set properties of axes using 'gca' handle. In Matlab 2013

```
set(gca,'XLim',[0,Xmax];
```

or in 2014b (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html)

```
gca.Xlim = [0, Xmax];
```